# I am unable to store unique email and username in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

I have make username and email unique in migration but it is allowing same email and username entry in database.

```
$table->string('userName')->unique();
$table->string('email')->unique();
```

Here is the screenshot of the table:
[Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5aZq.png)

Comment: Empty the database and try again adding the unique constraint. Verify the later with the schema, not by adding new data (keep the database empty until you know it is fixed in the schema).

Comment: Did you run those migrations successfully?

Comment: Go to the ```structure``` tab in phpmyadmin and verify there is ```unique``` labelled on the username and email field.

Comment: @brombeer yes migrations run successfully and data is being entered in table from signup form but it is allowing duplicate entries of email and username.

Comment: @Innovin Thanks it did work. But will I have to go to each table manually and do it? If you can tell if this problem can be solved by migration code. Itll be helpful

Comment: "_@Innovin Thanks it did work..._" That sounds like the migrations did _not_ run successfully

Comment: @RehmanAli Delete all the migrations from phpmyadmin  in ```migrations``` table. Then  run ```php artisan migrate``` again.

Comment: @Innovin or php artisan migrate:fresh

Comment: @AdemirŠehić Suggestion of Innovin worked for me

Comment: yes, same thing, different approach. When you use migrate:fresh it drops all the tables in database that came from migrations